# Mirror iPad 2 display to Mac WITHOUT Airplay

Tags: mac, ipad, airplay

I'd like to mirror my iPad 2 display to my Mac running OSX 10.6 WITHOUT using AirPlay, because the app I'm running on my iPad won't show the content using AirPlay or using the traditional output at the bottom (like running a cable from there to HDMI on my TV).

How can I accomplish this? Are there any app combinations that let you simply mirror the iPad display to the Mac over wi-fi without using AirPlay?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no way to mirror your iPad to your Mac without jail breaking it and installing DisplayOut and getting some cable. There is just no way for the Mac to know what is on the iPad without something on the iPad and on the Mac that syncs with eachother.

Answer (score -1):

I use Airserver to mirror my iPad on my Mac. It's been flawless for me. Very simple to set up

Comment: That appears to use AirPlay, which I specifically said I don't want to use.